# Neutral current

Tags: current, mains, wiring

I have an old switchboard with a 16 mm<sup>2</sup> mains cable and a 16mm<sup>2</sup> neutral return. At a different date, someone has added another 16mm<sup>2</sup> single main cable to the board. The two phases are feed from 2 × 63 amp fuses.

They have rewired the board to balance the two phases. I'm just asking if the neutral is capable of carrying the load of the two phases?

Comment: does this belong on DIY.SE perhaps? it's more a question for an electrician. Also, I'm guessing by 16mm you mean 16mm²?

Comment: Yes 16mm squared sorry I am on my phone I have asked an electrical he said it would be fine. I could be wrong but maybe he is thinking about a 3 phase balance load.

Comment: Is this a ***split-phase*** North American power mains? (It sounds as though it may be since you say "balance the two phases.")

Answer (score 1):

So long as the two phase conductors are tied to different phases from the power source, you are okay.

When you have a number of different loads on each phase, the Neutral conductor carries the **DIFFERNCE** between the two phases.

It does not matter whether the supply is a split-phase system as used in North America or any two of the phases of a 3-phase power source. The Neutral carries only the difference current.